# Не переведено выпадающее меню при клике на pollice verso в рекламном блоке Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: дефект, статус-отклонено, локализация

С недавних пор вижу подобные рекламные блоки:

[image: Задать вопрос]

При наведении курсора на блок в его левом верхнем углу появляются 2 пальца, обращённые кверху и книзу. При клике на тот, что повёрнут вниз, выпадает непереведённое меню:

[image: Выпадающее меню]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Данная панель предоставляется сервисом [Adzerk](https://www.adzerk.com/), через который мы размещаем рекламу. У нас нет возможности изменить эти строки.

П. С. На будущее мы определенно запросим возможность локализации у Adzerk.